# string concatenation problem

Tags: asp.net

Please how this string concatenation taking place?
i am really confuse what is happening why that slash i there and how the double quotes are used

```
SessionStateItemCollection items = new SessionStateItemCollection();

items["LastName"] = "Wilson";
items["FirstName"] = "Dan";

foreach (string s in items.Keys)
  Response.Write("items[\"" + s + "\"] = " + items[s].ToString() + "<br />");

//here i am looking for explanation please elaborate me on this please
Response.Write("items[\"" + s + "\"] = " + items[s].ToString() + "<br />");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slash is escaping the quote. Basically it is going to write the name in quotes inside brackets. For your example the output would be:

```
items["Wilson"] = Wilson<br />
```

The escaping happens for the character directly after the backslash `\`. So `\"` is escaped to `"`. The following `"` is stopping the string and you are appending the `s` variable which in turn is the current item in the foreach loop.

Here is a [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/csharpfaq/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available) on escape characters.

Comment: not clear sit which quote is escaped please elaborate a bit o this

Comment: I added more description and a link.

Answer (score 3):

Only the `\"` (doubles quotes immed after the backslash) is escaped.

Answer (score 1):

The backslash escapes the `"`.  This tells the compiler that you just want a literal double-quote, rather than ending the string literal.

Comment: so when slash encounters, the first double quotes will be ignored is it true?

Comment: It means the double-quote will just be a regular character in the string.